# Filtering objects by fuzzy word search

Tags: python, django

I have a list of objects with a name attribute, and I want to be able to sort it fuzzily. For example, this is what the objects look like as a JSON:

```
{
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Test445'
},
{
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Test444'
},
{
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Name44'
},
```

I want to be able to input a name search string like `Test` which will return the first 2 objects, since `Test` is in both `Test445` and `Test444`.

Is there a way I can do this easily?

Comment: if you know that it's text and numeric, you can use `name.rstrip(string.digits)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#contains) or [`startswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#startswith) filter:

```
Entry.objects.filter(name__contains='Test')
Entry.objects.filter(name__startswith='Test')
```

For case-insensitive checks, use [`icontains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) and [`istartswith`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#istartswith).

Comment: Damn, that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!. Is there a way to make it so the search isn't case sensitive? Right now `Test` is different than `test` so if I do a search for `test`, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Rohinder sure, added to the answer. Thanks.